# use the iteration object multiple times (Rust)

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust. I need to get a list of files and directories in a folder, however I can't access the iteration object more than once.

Of course, this can be done using else, but I would like to know what to do in such a situation.

```
for d in fs::read_dir("./").unwrap() {
    if d.unwrap().path().is_dir() {
        continue;
    } else if d.unwrap().path().is_file() { //except here
        continue;         
    }
```

Comment: Store the result of `d.unwrap().path()` to a variable up front, call `is_dir`/`is_file` on that stored variable? I'm unclear on what can't be reused, but if you extract the value just once, then reuse what you extracted it should be fine, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm new to rust. I need to get a list of files and directories in a folder, however I can't access the iteration object more than once.

You can understand why, and how to fix it, by looking at the documentation. Specifically the `self` types:

[`read_dir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_dir.html) returns [an iterator of `Result<DirEntry>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.ReadDir.html#impl-Iterator), so that's what `d` is.

[`Result::unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap) takes `self`, so it consumes the result itself, meaning after the first call to `d.unwrap()` there is no `d` anymore.

Your solutions then are:

- since `path`, `is_dir`, and `is_file` all take `&self` as ShadowRanger notes you can just store the unwrapped `DirEntry`, or the paths
- alternatively, you can use [`Result::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.as_ref) to get a `Result<&DirEntry>`, which you can then unwrap to get an `&DirEntry` of which you can get the path, this only needs a `&Result`, so it does not consume the `Result` itself